# Angular material radio button label and VoiceOver/ScreenReader

Tags: angular, accessibility, angular-material2, voiceover

I have an Angular Material mat-radio-group.  When I test it with Apple's VoiceOver, it reads each radio label as "[the label] and one more item"

For example,

`<mat-radio-button value="envelope">Envelope</mat-radio-button>`

Is read out loud as "Envelope and one more item" when focused. Why?

Here's the whole set:

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="My Package Type" [(ngModel)]="myPackageType" class="radio-package-type mat-radio-small">
   <mat-radio-button value="box">Box</mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button value="envelope">Envelope</mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button value="irregular">Irregular</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Here is the rendered HTML copied from dev tools:

```
<mat-radio-group
  _ngcontent-gkg-c241=""
  role="radiogroup"
  aria-label="My Package Type"
  class="mat-radio-group radio-package-type mat-radio-small ng-pristine ng-valid is-value ng-touched"
  ng-reflect-model="box"
  ><mat-radio-button
    _ngcontent-gkg-c241=""
    value="box"
    class="mat-radio-button mat-accent mat-radio-checked"
    ng-reflect-value="box"
    tabindex="-1"
    id="mat-radio-2"
    ><label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-2-input"
      ><div class="mat-radio-container">
        <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
        <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden"
          id="mat-radio-2-input"
          tabindex="0"
          name="mat-radio-group-0"
          value="box"
        />
        <div
          mat-ripple=""
          class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"
          ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]"
          ng-reflect-disabled="false"
          ng-reflect-centered="true"
          ng-reflect-radius="20"
          ng-reflect-animation="[object Object]"
        >
          <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-radio-label-content">
        <span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>Box
      </div></label
    ></mat-radio-button
  ><mat-radio-button
    _ngcontent-gkg-c241=""
    value="envelope"
    class="mat-radio-button mat-accent"
    ng-reflect-value="envelope"
    tabindex="-1"
    id="mat-radio-3"
    ><label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-3-input"
      ><div class="mat-radio-container">
        <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
        <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden"
          id="mat-radio-3-input"
          tabindex="0"
          name="mat-radio-group-0"
          value="envelope"
        />
        <div
          mat-ripple=""
          class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"
          ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]"
          ng-reflect-disabled="false"
          ng-reflect-centered="true"
          ng-reflect-radius="20"
          ng-reflect-animation="[object Object]"
        >
          <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-radio-label-content">
        <span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>Envelope
      </div></label
    ></mat-radio-button
  ><mat-radio-button
    _ngcontent-gkg-c241=""
    value="irregular"
    class="mat-radio-button mat-accent"
    ng-reflect-value="irregular"
    tabindex="-1"
    id="mat-radio-4"
    ><label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-4-input"
      ><div class="mat-radio-container">
        <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
        <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden"
          id="mat-radio-4-input"
          tabindex="0"
          name="mat-radio-group-0"
          value="irregular"
        />
        <div
          mat-ripple=""
          class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"
          ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]"
          ng-reflect-disabled="false"
          ng-reflect-centered="true"
          ng-reflect-radius="20"
          ng-reflect-animation="[object Object]"
        >
          <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-radio-label-content">
        <span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>Irregular
      </div></label
    ></mat-radio-button
  ></mat-radio-group
>
```

Comment: can you paste the outputted HTML into your question, looks fine in your question but I suspect the generated markup is not quite right or has additional items added that are causing this behaviour.

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Hard to tell from the mess of HTML it creates but I noticed the label is wrapped around everything but also associated with `for="mat-radio-3-input"`, this is likely to cause strange behaviour. Additionally because the label is wrapped around everything the cause is likely to be the "ripple" but I need to see how it changes based on focus, checked etc. Sorry to be a pain but any chance you can turn it into a fiddle so I can inspect a few things, fiddle a bit and come back with more than just educated guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem (macOS 10.15.3, Safari 13.0.5 and 10.15.4, 13.1, I couldn't reproduce in Mac Chrome 80 or iOS 13.3.1 Safari). It seems to occur when a `<label>` has child elements with display:block, particularly if there's either a mix of child elements with and without display: block or a mix of TextNodes and elements with `display:block`.

In your case, the label is both implicit (input is child of label) and explicit (label has for attribute referencing input's id). While that is needless duplication (as is adding `tagindex="0"` to an `<input>` element), it's not related to the problem. I've reproduced the problem with implicit-only and explicit-only labels and inputs. There seem to be two things required to reproduce the problem:

1. `<label>` changed to `display:block`
2. `<label>` has at least one `display:block` child element but not all children with `display:block`

Changing the label element so one of those two requirements are not met seems to fix it.

```html
<!-- VoiceOver is saying "First Nameandone more item, edit text" -->
<!-- implicit -->
<label style="display:block"> 
    <span style="display:block">First Name</span>
    <input type="text"> 
</label>

<!-- explicit -->
<div>
    <label for="firstname3" class="block"> 
        First Name
        <span style="display:block">Test</span>
    </label>
    <input id="firstname3" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippets are for demonstrating the problem in Mac Safari without all the complexity of the example in the original question.